# Can not add this repository to ppa

Tags: 12.04, php

I want add php5.6 to php repository by this command

```
root@precise32:~# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

Why do I receive this error?

```
 Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~ondrej/+archive/php5) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

Comment: Because it does not exist?

Comment: And PLEASE do NOT use sudo when root.

Answer (score 1):

You got the wrong PPA. [See this link](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php):

> Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.0, PHP 7.1 and most requested extensions are included.
>
> PLEASE DON'T USE PHP 5.4 OR PHP 5.5. The PHP 5.5 and later are no longer supported with security updates, therefore they are not included in this repository.

It seems you need to use ...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

Also take note that PHP 5.6 or higher is not supported in apache below 2.4 and 2.4 is not in 12.04. You will also need to update apache if you did not yet do that.

Comment: when i do that command i can not update my php version. please help me